# Gitlab Pages: Failed to verify domain ownership

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

This morning I got emails for each of my Gitlab Pages that are hosted on custom domains, saying that the domain verification failed.

That's fine, because I don't think I ever verified them in the first place - good on Gitlab for getting this going.

When I head on over the the Settings>Pages>Domain_Details on each repo, I see the instructions to create the following record:

```
_gitlab-pages-verification-code.blog.ollyfg.com TXT gitlab-pages-verification-code={32_digit_long_code}
```

On creating this record, and clicking the "Verify Ownership" button, I get the message "Failed to verify domain ownership".

I have ensured that the record *is* set, and calling

```
dig -t txt +short _gitlab-pages-verification-code.blog.ollyfg.com
```

Returns:

```
"gitlab-pages-verification-code={same_32_digit_long_code}"
```

Is this a bug in Gitlab? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Wait 24 hours for propagation of DNS and try again.

Comment: Seeing the same thing here, except using a rootlevel TXT instead of the `_gitlab-pages-verification-code.` subdomain

Comment: Probably it did not propagate to one of your secondary dns servers and GitLab was using this exact slave for verification. At least I think that is what caused trouble in my case. Verification succeeded after I removed the stale server from my zone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wait for sometime, it worked for me. Initially, having the same problem as you mentioned.

Also, you may find this page useful: https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_three.md#dns-txt-record

It might be worthwhile, trying with:
`blog.ollyfg.com`
instead of: `_gitlab-pages-verification-code.blog.ollyfg.com`

Comment: To make things more clear, as @ryu mentioned, this issue may be caused because of the multiple purposes of the domain - (email, non-gitlab usage, etc.)

I've faced same issue when trying to use the subdomain. To resolve it, I've changed my DNS record to the type A, and added DNS TXT record with a key provided by gitlab. It finally helped.
`subdomain.domain.zone A 52.167.214.135`
`subdomain.domain.zone TXT gitlab-pages-verification-code=your_code_here`

Answer (score 15):

The docs (and the verification page) were a little confusing for me.  Here's what worked for me, on GoDaddy:

---

#### A Record:

**Name**: @

**Value**: 35.185.44.232

#### CNAME:

**Name**: example.com

**Value**: username.gitlab.io

#### TXT Record:

**Name**: @

**Value**: gitlab-pages-verification-code=00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff

---

Verified with Gitlab, and also:

`dig -t txt +short example.com`

Comment: don't need the CNAME record if you didn't use any subdomain. And don't need A record if you use subdomain. Worked for me in both case.

Comment: @Atiq In fact, I did need both A and CNAME for it to work, and I am not using a subdomain.

Comment: Interesting. I configure it today and i didn't need cname for my domain. may be they update the system.

Comment: But why `@` for name when according to GitLab must be `_gitlab-pages-verification-code.gms-ai.com`?

Comment: Not sure about this @VitalyZdanevich maybe they changed their documentation again

Comment: The @ in the TXT record made all the difference for me, many thanks!

Comment: It solved my issue as well (for DreamHost registrar). I use both top-level domain and subdomains.

Answer (score 9):

Here is how to get a `subdomain.domain.com` point to `namespace.gitlab.io/project-name` with [Gandi](https://www.gandi.net/en).

The `CNAME` and `TXT` records generated by GitLab when adding a new subdomain to a project via `Settings > Pages > New Domain` did **not** work in my case. The exact non-working records were `mysubdomain.mydomain.com CNAME mynamespace.gitlab.io.` and `_gitlab-pages-verification-code.mysubdomain.mydomain.com TXT gitlab-pages-verification-code=00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff`.

Modifications like `mysubdomain CNAME mynamespace.gitlab.io.` (with and without a dot at the end) did **not** work, either (`ping mysubdomain.mydomain.com` said *unknown host*).

Using an `A` record and a `TXT` record with only the subdomain in the record's name field **does work** in my case. Here are the exact working records:

```
mysubdomain 1800 IN A 35.185.44.232
mysubdomain 1800 IN TXT "gitlab-pages-verification-code=00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff"
```

Note that the `namespace.gitlab.io` IP address has changed from `52.167.214.135` to `35.185.44.232` in 2018.

Wait as least 30 minutes to get the records propagate.

In my case GitLab also verified the domain automatically, I did not need to click the `Verify` button.

Comment: Me too. And just in case someone as ignorant as me is also wrestling with this: I was able to map two different Gitlab pages projects to two subdomains of the same DNS: `en.example.org` to `namespace.gitlab.io` and `fr.example.org` to `namespace.gitlab.io/french`. The documentation seemed to suggest that I needed `CNAME` records to do this, but I followed these instructions and used `A` records, and it worked.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot, thanks. However, I like to add here another issue I encountered with a specific subdomain `WWW`. Recommended method is failed for me as _Gandi_ is not allowing a `TXT` type entry for `WWW` (quite normal IMHO). So instead of changing `_gitlab-pages-verification-code.mysubdomain.mydomain.com to m̀ysubdomain`, I changed it to `_gitlab-pages-verification-code.mysubdomain` and it works.  

BTW, this is related with how _Gandi_ handles DNS entry names, it always adds mydomain.com. It is clear when you edit DNS records in _table mode_, but not obvious in _text mode_.

Comment: @trblnc can confirm your method worked for www on google domains; nothing else I've tried here worked!

Answer (score 4):

I really get a hard time to make it work. But in the end below settings worked for me.

## GoDaddy

### domain.com

#### *A* record

```
+-----------+---------------------+
|   Host    |          @          |
+-----------+---------------------+
| Points To | 35.185.44.232       |
+-----------+---------------------+
```

To Verify your domain Add **TXT** record

#### *TXT* record

```
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|   Host    |                                @                                |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| TXT Value | gitlab-pages-verification-code=00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

### subdomain.domain.com

#### *CNAME* record

```
+-----------+---------------------+
|   Host    |  subdomain          |
+-----------+---------------------+
| Points To | namespace.gitlab.io |
+-----------+---------------------+
```

To Verify your domain Add **TXT** record

#### *TXT* record

```
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|   Host    |             _gitlab-pages-verification-code.subdomain           |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| TXT Value | gitlab-pages-verification-code=00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Note** subdomain and verification code will be found under settings>page (create/details)
GitLab Pages IP on GitLab.com has been changed
from *52.167.214.135* to *35.185.44.232* in **2018**

Answer (score 4):

For GoDaddy (April 2020), I had to do the following:

```
|Type |Name                           |Value                                      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|A    |example.com (or @)             |35.185.44.232                              |
|TXT  |_gitlab-pages-verification-code|gitlab-pages-verification-code=blahblahblah|
|A    |www                            |35.185.44.232                              |
|CNAME|www.example.com                |example.gitlab.io                          |
|TXT  |_gitlab-pages-verification-code|gitlab-pages-verification-code=blahblahblah|
|     |(or _gitlab-pages.verification-|                                           |
|     |code.www)                      |                                           |
```

While the documentation said to use `_gitlab-pages-verification-code.example.com` and `_gitlab-pages-verification-code.www.example.com`, those did not work for me, and I could see within seconds after changing and re-checking my verification status that it changed from unverified to verified, and vice versa.

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/custom_domains_ssl_tls_certification/dns_concepts.html

Answer (score 0):

It's 2021, and this issue still happens. Can't verify domain with gitlab's suggested CNAME and TXT. Had to use on godaddy:

```
subdomain A 35.185.44.232
subdomain TXT gitlab-pages-verification-code=####
```