# Connect GitLab Page with GoDaddy Domain

Tags: dns, gitlab, hosting, shared-hosting, gitlab-pages

How can I connect my GoDaddy Domain https://baharalidurrani.me with my GitLab Pages https://baharalidurrani.gitlab.io/domain
Also guide me about the naked domain and www domain.
Please explain me the following DNS related Terms:
NAMESERVER, A, CNAME, MX, TXT, SRV, AAAA,CAA.
I am developing my website using ReactJS and I like GitLab because of the CI features.
Thanks

Comment: I found this answer very useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61200777/351076